# Two Excel VBA user form can have the same value?

Tags: vba, excel

I’m working on a Userform’s data, but there’s a problem with save or new function. For example, there’s two user form, Useform1 is for editable data and Usernew is for add new data to the excel sheet, them both open from the same window, but Usernew is dependent from Userform1. However, if the user opens the Userform1 then user new the data will be merge from other excel data. Example Userform1 open the entire row data, in this case name: Katie, pass: chuang, etc. In other hand Usernew should open the same data as before, but open a random entire row data.

**Here is the code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("a2:Z10000")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Then

       UserForm1.cmbEmp = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
       UserForm1.ldlcolor = Cells(Target.Row, 3)
       UserForm1.ldlname = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
       UserForm1.ldlpresI = Cells(Target.Row, 14)
       UserForm1.ldlpopular = Cells(Target.Row, 30)
       UserForm1.miRow = Target.Row
       UserForm1.ComboBox_1 = Cells(Target.Row, 38)
       UserForm1.ldlres1 = Cells(Target.Row, 39)
       UserForm1.ComboBox_2 = Cells(Target.Row, 40)
       UserForm1.ldlres2 = Cells(Target.Row, 41)
       UserForm1.ComboBox_3 = Cells(Target.Row, 42)
       UserForm1.ldlres3 = Cells(Target.Row, 43)
       UserForm1.ldlpass = Cells(Target.Row, 45)
       UserForm1.lblusername = Cells(Target.Row, 44)
       UserForm1.ldlplaz = Cells(Target.Row, 8)
       UserForm1.Show 

    End If

    Usernew.cmbEmp = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    Usernew.ldlcolor = Cells(Target.Row, 3)
    Usernew.ldlname = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
    Usernew.ldlpresI = Cells(Target.Row, 14)
    Usernew.ldlpopular = Cells(Target.Row, 30)
    Usernew.miRow = Target.Row
    Usernew.ComboBox_1 = Cells(Target.Row, 38)
    Usernew.ldlres1 = Cells(Target.Row, 39)
    Usernew.ComboBox_2 = Cells(Target.Row, 40)
    Usernew.ldlres2 = Cells(Target.Row, 41)
    Usernew.ComboBox_3 = Cells(Target.Row, 42)
    Usernew.ldlres3 = Cells(Target.Row, 43)
    Usernew.ldlpass = Cells(Target.Row, 45)
    Usernew.lblusername = Cells(Target.Row, 44)
    Usernew.ldlplaz = Cells(Target.Row, 8)

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I really do not see what you want to do. Please explain what is the purpose of UserForm1 and UserNew. Is UserNew a form to enter the data of a new user?

Comment: Both form is for enter data, but one of them is for enter new data and the other one is for edit data.

Comment: So in case I change existing data UserForm1 is opened and filled with the data from that row in the other case Usernew is opened and is populated with empty data from the empty row?

Comment: That's right, but if the row is filled the Usernew should be populated with that row's data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write back the data from the form to the sheet then you'll have to do so. Here is an example:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

Dim lngLastRow As Long

With Worksheets(1)
    lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'create a new row below all existing rows (append)
    lngLastRow = lngLastRow + 1
    'write back the data to the sheet
    Cells(lngLastRow, 1) = Usernew.cmbEmp
    Cells(lngLastRow, 3) = Usernew.ldlcolor
    Cells(lngLastRow, 1) = Usernew.ldlname
    '...
    'complete code with the other cells and form controls
End With

End Sub
```

Note: you'll have to add the above code to your form in order to make it work.

Still, there is one question to be answered. How do you tell if a row in the Excel sheet contains an existing user or if that is an empty record? At the moment your code suggests that all rows in this sheet from row 2 to row 10000 contain existing users. But when you add a new user then this no longer valid.

Hence I suggest that you change your current event like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo AddNewUser
If Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 45)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count > 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Existing user
End If
Exit Sub

AddNewUser:
    'New User
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

If any of the cells in that row contains data then it is an existing user. If all cells in that row are empty then this is a new user. (With "any" I mean the cells you refer to in your current VBA code. This seems to includes column 1 to column 45.)

Comment: I  found the solution, but I gonna  marked your answer cause you did work so hard. I just move all the Usernew code before the  UserForm1.Show.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same form but have Add New and Edit data. If clicked on Add new it goes to the last row in the sheet and updates.

If clicked on Edit, you have a search box which is enabled now and based on the unique key of the data the fields get populated and user gets to edit.

For example they search for specific roll no# and that row data is feed into the form now.